# Drive API manifest and integration with Drive App

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I have an Android app that creates its own files in Google Drive with the mime type `application/vnd.test.type`

I would like to make my app handle requests for this file type when opened by the Google Drive app as described [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/integrate-android-ui).

My activity to handle the opening of the file is in my manifest file as follows:

```xml
    <activity android:name="DriveHandlerActivity" 
              android:label="@string/app_name" 
              android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
              android:exported="true" >
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.apps.drive.APP_ID" 
                   android:value="id=MY_ID"/> 
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="com.google.android.apps.drive.DRIVE_OPEN"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.test.type"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

When I attempt to open the file in the Google Drive app I get the "Open with..." dialog as expected with my app listed as the only entry capable of dealing with this file type. Unfortunately after confirming the action, I then get a dialog thats says.

[image: Error Dialog]

My only option then is to press the "Cancel" button which returns me to the Google Drive app.

I am not totally convinced I have the meta data correct as the ID is referred to using different names depending on where you look. Some [documentation calls it the **App ID**](https://developers.google.com/drive/integrate-android-ui), some call it the **Project ID** [(See here at 26:44)](http://youtube.googleapis.com/v/xRGyzqD-vRg).  I have tried using both the "Project ID" as listed in my Google Apis Console and also the project number (from the URL) on the same page. I get the same error regardless of which value I choose as the ID.

As far as I am aware, the next step should be to handle the intent in my app but due to the error described, the intent never arrives. Can anybody tell me what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: Are you using emulator or real device ?

Comment: real Galaxy Nexus running Jellybean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's currently an issue that requires your application to be listed in the [Chrome Webstore](https://developers.google.com/drive/listing) (even to trusted testers only) in order for the `Open With` flow to work.

However, even if the issue is resolved, your app won't be able to access the file until the [Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/google-play-services/) API is released. 
The only work around would be to request authorization for the full Drive scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` which is not recommended but useful for debugging.

I'll update this answer when the Chrome Webstore limitation is resolved.

Comment: Excellent thank you. Update the docs to this effect maybe? I wasted a lot of time on this and only tried it because of your demo at IO. Can you tell me exactly which ID I should be using in the manifest. It isn't clear to me. Thanks.

Comment: The ID you should use is the one from the API Project and is also part of the URL. Example: `https://code.google.com/apis/console/#project:<APP_ID>` (it should only be numbers). I was hoping for Google Play Services to be released before developers start trying :-/

Comment: Is the Chrome Webstore requirement still there?  I've been attempting drive integration, just ran into the same issue (internal error occurred).